# Changing tense in reported questions

Tags: reported-speech

In a book published by *Merriam-Webster*, the direct question **When is she seeing them again?** has been changed to a reported question as following:

**He asked when she would be seeing them again.**

My question is, why has the *present continuous* in the direct question been changed to *would be + verb/ing* in the reported question?

Answer (score 3):

Good question. The answer is that when reporting a question, it isn't necessary to report the exact verb tense as the original. You've probably been taught to perfectly back-shift every tense, which is the right way to teach students at first, but the only real requirement in reporting someone's speech is that the meaning stays consistent from the original to the reported speech.

It's like if someone tells you a story, and you tell someone else, you're unlikely to preserve the sentences or even paragraphs, let alone the precise verb tenses.

With your example sentences, the book expects the reader to already understand that
"*When is she seeing them again?*" is functionally equivalent to "*When will she be seeing them again?*", so I'm guessing (hoping?) this is not a book aimed at ESL students exposed to reported speech for the first time.

The reported form of "*When will she be seeing them again?*" is "*He asked when she would be seeing them again.*"

All meaning is preserved.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks very much. +1 By the way, the book is not for those who are going to learn reported speech for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like present continuous, but it is equivalent to "When will she see them
again."
Here is a discussion of "future with present progressive"
[Lawless English](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/?p=5126)

Comment: I went through that but which part answers my question?

Comment: Your question, as I read it, was why there is a tense change from "present continuous". The tense is not present continuous, but future as explained in that link. If you are asking why a different word is used when changing to reported speech, that is just the way the language works. It is not a tense change.